# What's the easy way to create a cluster with 2 nodes on the same machine?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm testing [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.com/) and I'm trying to create a simple cluster with 2 nodes on a single machine (on Fedora)

I'm launching a first instance named Node1:

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch -Des.node.name=Node1 -Des.http.port=9200
```

And a second instance named Node2 in another terminal:

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch -Des.node.name=Node2 -Des.http.port=9201
```

The console output is the following for both commands:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (node).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

GET `http://127.0.0.1:9200` gives me:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Node1",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "f1585f096d3f3985e73456debdc1a0745f512bbc",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-04-16T14:27:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.7"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and GET `http://127.0.0.1:9201` gives me

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Node2",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "f1585f096d3f3985e73456debdc1a0745f512bbc",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-04-16T14:27:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.7"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

That looks good but now if I get the cluster health I have different results on 9200 and 9201:

GET `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true`

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 6,
  "active_shards" : 6,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 6
}
```

GET `http://127.0.0.1:9201/_cluster/health?pretty=true`

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

Why do I have only 1 node on the same cluster? Why is it green and also yellow? Looks like the cluster is not working...

How do I make this works? 
Where are the [Zen Discovery](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html) logs?

Related questions:

- [elasticsearch: auto node discovery not happening, missing anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611254/elasticsearch-auto-node-discovery-not-happening-missing-anything)
- [Multiple nodes in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477303/multiple-nodes-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Can you start two nodes minus your additional settings and they discover each other?

Comment: Two times `sudo bin/elasticsearch` without any settings gives me the same result.. (with autogenerated node names and port)

Comment: Looks like the two nodes cannot properly communicate, I'd look for firewalls or similar. They are effectively forming two different clusters with same name. Maybe they are using two different devices?

Comment: They are both on the same machine

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch nodes cannot share the same data directory. So you need to add an additional parameter: `-Des.data.path=/path/to/data`

```js
 sudo bin/elasticsearch -Des.node.name=Node1 -Des.http.port=9200 
   -Des.data.path=/path/to/data1

 sudo bin/elasticsearch -Des.node.name=Node2 -Des.http.port=9201 
   -Des.data.path=/path/to/data2
```

That should work for you. Also, note that in this case you do not need to specify the port numbers as Elasticsearch will automatically grab the next available free port, starting with 9200 by default.

Comment: This is not true :) The data directory is structured in such a way so that you can start multiple nodes from the same location without having to change anything. The data dir will contain a node counter, the number you see under `{cluster_name}/nodes`, so that the second node that gets started will just increment the node id of the highest found counter and use it as its data directory name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by setting the parameter network.host to 127.0.0.1 in the config file elasticsearch.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you have two separate clusters with one node each.  What type of discovery are you using, unicast or multicast?
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html

For the ZenDiscovery logs, start your elasticsearch instance with an extra parameter to get verbose logging:
`-Dlogger.zen.discovery=TRACE`